# Can't horizontally center TextView

Tags: android

I'm new to android and I'm trying to create a simple TextView thingy. I can't horizontally center it, though. Here's my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textSize="45sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change orientation to vertical

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textSize="45sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the orientation to vertical resolved the problem

Comment: You can also use RelativeLayout to easily position the views on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the orientation to 'horizontal' and add the gravity property set to 'center_horizontal'

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:textSize="45sp" />
```